# Conda using /usr/local/bin/python instead of conda environment python

Tags: python, path, anaconda, environment-variables, conda

After I activate my conda environment and I run `which python`, I get the following

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

As you can see it doesn't use the python which should be in the conda environment, i.e
`/Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/envs/po/bin/python`

How can I fix this issue? I'm using MacOS

This is my `conda info -a`

```
# conda environments:
#
base                     /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3
discoe                   /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/envs/discoe
po                    *  /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/envs/po
py38                     /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38
test                     /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/envs/test

sys.version: 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 08:50:36)
...
sys.prefix: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3
sys.executable: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
conda location: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda
conda-build: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-build
conda-content-trust: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-content-trust
conda-convert: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-convert
conda-debug: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-debug
conda-develop: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-develop
conda-env: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-env
conda-index: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-index
conda-inspect: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-inspect
conda-metapackage: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-metapackage
conda-pack: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-pack
conda-render: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-render
conda-repo: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-repo
conda-server: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-server
conda-skeleton: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-skeleton
conda-token: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-token
conda-verify: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-verify
user site dirs:

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: po
CONDA_EXE: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda
CONDA_PREFIX: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/envs/po
CONDA_PREFIX_1: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER: (po)
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
CONDA_ROOT: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3
CONDA_SHLVL: 2
CURL_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
DISCOE_PATH: /Users/zeus/Project/discoe
PATH: /Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/zeus/.poetry/bin:/Users/zeus/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/envs/po/bin:.:/Users/zeus/.local/bin:/Users/zeus/.local/bin
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
SSL_CERT_FILE: <not set>
```

this is what my $PATH is `/Users/zeus/.poetry/bin:/Users/zeus/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/zeus/opt/anaconda3/envs/po/bin:.:/Users/zeus/.local/bin:/Users/zeus/.local/bin`

I activate my conda environment by this command `conda activate po`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve the issue, you need to deactivate all Conda environments completely. This includes not only your specific project environment but also the base (default) environment.

Here are the steps:

1. If you are in a specific Conda environment, deactivate it using the command: `conda deactivate`
2. You might notice that you are still in the base Conda environment. To deactivate from the base environment, use the same command again: `conda deactivate`

Now, you should be completely out of all Conda environments.

The reason behind this is that Conda and other Python environment managers manipulate the system path. When you activate a Conda environment, it prepends the path of the active environment's binary directory to your system `PATH`. So, when you're in a Conda environment, Python executables and scripts installed in that environment take precedence over system-wide installed ones. This is why it's necessary to deactivate all Conda environments to ensure you're using the system-wide Python.

For more details, you can refer to this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/python-the-system-path-and-how-conda-and-pyenv-manipulate-it-234f8e8bbc3e

Comment: This is not a complete answer. I have to go to that link and read all the details to find out how to to do it. The answer should contain the complete solution.

Comment: the solution is to deactivate out of all the conda environments completely which I've posted in the answer. The article is just a reference i used. I don't want to copy paste the entire article and post it here

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH` before the `anaconda3` path. That could come from your `~/.zshrc`/`~/.bashrc`/`~/.profile` files, but somewhere the `$PATH` is being modified so that the Anaconda `bin` folder is after `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue and solved.

1. Go to your usr directory and find "/home/usr/.bash_profile". Mine shows:

> ```
> # User specific environment and startup programs
>
> PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
>
> export PATH
> ```

2. Insert the following line and save the "/home/usr/.bash_profile" file as:

> ```
> # User specific environment and startup programs
>
> PATH="/home/YOUR_USR_NAME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
>
> PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
>
> export PATH
> ```

3. Issue solved.